# The degree of (projectively) dual variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a (smooth) hypersurface of degree $d$ (over $\mathbb C$). Let $X^*\subset \mathbb P^{n*}$ be the dual variety (in the senese that all hyperplanes tangent to $X$, together with the natural scheme structure). How can we compute the degree of $X^*$?

Comment: You can find this in 3264 and All That, Proposition 2.9.

Comment: @loch Nice! thank you.

Comment: Another reference is the first chapter of "Discriminants, resultants, and multidimensional determinants" by Gelfand, Kapranov and Zelevinsky.